# Why does (passport) middleware function fire with app.get, but not app.post

Tags: node.js, express, middleware, passport.js

I have the following middleware function:

```
function isLoggedIn(req, res, next) {

  if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
    console.log('***User is logged in***');
    next();
  } else {

    res.redirect('/');
    console.log('***User IS NOT logged in***');
  }
}
```

This works just fine in the following GET route:

```
app.get('/profile', isLoggedIn, function(req, res) {
    res.render('profile.ejs', {
      user: req.user // get the user out of session and pass to template
    });
  });
```

However, when I try to plug in the isLoggedIn function into a POST route, it doesn't fire:

```
app.post('/add', isLoggedIn, function(req, res) {
    console.log('Success');
  });
```

Why doesn't my function fire with app.post, but with app.get, it fires?

Answer (score 0):

If you're posting to the url with a promise library like jQuery or Axios, then `res.redirect` will not change the page the browser is on. In this case, you would need to handle the response of your post resulting in a status code of 302 (default status code return on Expresses redirect) then have that redirect the page to where you need (on the front end)

Comment: It's not even getting to the res.redirect portion of the code, the function is not firing at all on the POST request. I can change app.post to app.get in the above route (/add), and the isLoggedIn function fires (I see the message printing to the console). When I change it back to .post, the function no longer fires at all.